# React Slider images changing on Click not working (uncaught error too many re-renders)

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a React slider for images. But I'm getting an error that says Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. If anyone can just point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. I'm certain that the issue lays within the onClick aspect of the sliderDots mapping.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Sliderdots from '../CarasouelDots/Sliderdots.component';
import './Slider.styles.scss'
import sliderImages from '../../MockImages/mockimages';


const Slider = () => {
    const images = sliderImages;
//Iterator
    const [img, setImg] = useState(0);
//Getting all shoe images from an object array
    const shoes = images.map(i => (i.shoe));
    const heading = images.map(i => (i.title));
    const content = images.map(i => (i.content))
    const numbers = shoes.map((i, index) => (index))
    const indexSet = (number) =>{
        setImg(number);
    }
//problem with onClick here??
    const sliderD = images.map((dot, index) => <Sliderdots key={index} onClick={indexSet(index)}/>);


    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => {
            img == shoes.length - 1 ? setImg(0) : setImg(img + 1)
        }, 4500)
    }, [img]);

    return (

        <div className='slider-container' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${shoes[img]})` }}>
            <div className='overlay'>
                <h1 className='introduction'>{heading[img]}</h1>
                <p className='content'>{content[img]}</p>
                <div className='dot-container'>
                    {sliderD}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Slider;
```

Comment: Don't use simple variable instead use useState variable and also in onClick use method expression instead of simple expression.

Comment: It should be `onClick={() => indexSet(index)}` or just `onClick={() => setImage(index)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your component is constantly rerendering is because your onClick property is actually a function call in disguise that gets executed every render:

```js
// This line actually calls the `indexSet` function each time!
const sliderD = images.map((dot, index) => <Sliderdots key={index} onClick={indexSet(index)}/>);
```

And since `indexSet` updates the state of the React component by calling `setImg`, the React component will always end up re-rendering when it reaches that line of code, and since that line of code always re-calls the `indexSet` function, your component will infinitely re-render.

To fix your code, you just need to replace that onClick property with an anonymous function:

```js
const sliderD = images.map((dot, index) => <Sliderdots key={index} onClick={() => indexSet(index)}/>);
```